# Entity Field Query OR condition,between node title and a custom field

Tags: entities, hooks

I am executing a query for searching in the node title and a field using LIKE.How do I use the OR condition?
`

```
function hook_somefunction($keys) {
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node', '=')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'product_display_one');
  //$query->addTag('customproductstag');
  $query->addMetaData('keys', $keys);
```

//both conditions below are working fine individually ,but I need to use OR in between them
  //$query->fieldCondition('field_usage_number', 'value','%'. $keys .'%', 'LIKE');
  //$query->propertyCondition('title',$keys .'%', 'LIKE');
  $result = $query->execute();
  return $result;
}

//This part below is not working
function hook_query_customproductstag_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  $keys = $query->getMetaData('keys');
  $or = db_or()
    ->fieldCondition('field_usage_number', 'value','%'. $keys .'%', 'LIKE')
    ->propertyCondition('title','%'.$keys .'%', 'LIKE');

$query->condition($or);
}  `

Thanks.

Comment: I still haven't found answer for this. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`

```
function hook_query_customproductstag_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  $keys = $query->getMetaData('keys');
  $or = db_or()
    //->fieldCondition('field_usage_number', 'value','%'. $keys .'%', 'LIKE')
    //->propertyCondition('title','%'.$keys .'%', 'LIKE');
    ->condition('usage.field_usage_number_value', '%' . db_like($keys) . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->condition('node.title', '%' . db_like($keys) . '%', 'LIKE');
```

$query->condition($or);
}  `

fieldCondition didn't work because db_or is not a part of entity query.